# Simplest sed to remove all duplicating anywhere in document

Tags: sed

How is sed simplest code to remove all duplicating lines anywhere in document

This reference script, I guess, do only such if it's consecutive only isn't it?

```
sed -E '$q; N; /^(.*)\n\1$/!{ P; D }; :L $d; s/.*\n//; N; /^(.*)\n\1$/bL; D
```

Please help out... will highly gratified

Comment: Have you attempted to solve it?

Comment: Does it have to be [tag:sed]?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;x;s/((\n[^\n]*).*)\2$/\1/;x;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Append each line to the hold space and remove it if it has occurred before.

At the end of file, remove the first introduced newline.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, assuming your input file looks like;

```
$ cat input_file
one
one
two
one
three
four
three
three
five
two
five
four
three
four
four
five
```

```
$ sed -n 'G;/^\(.*\n\).*\n\1$/d;H;P' input_file
one
two
three
four
five
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to remove all but the first instance of any duplicated lines in a file, right?

So that

```
alpha
beta
beta
gamma
beta
delta
alpha
delta
```

becomes

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

So don't use `sed`.  Use Perl to walk through the file line by line and only print the lines it has not seen before:

```
perl -ne'print unless $seen{$_}++' input.txt > output.txt
```